# Does 'select distinct' returns the first distinct value or last distinct?

Tags: sql, distinct

When I query

```
select distinct Name from Emp;
```

**Emp Table**

```
ID   Name
1    Sam
2    Tom
3    Sam
```

does this query return first distinct name(with ID=1) from duplicate names or last distinct name(with ID=3)

How the distinct keyword actually works in this context?

Comment: Which rdbms you are using?

Comment: Does it matter if it returns `'Sam'` or `'Sam'`? Can you tell the difference?

Comment: It neither returns "the first row" nor the "last row". It returns the distinct **values** of the `name` column. It doesn't matter to which row they belong.

Comment: @PraveenPrasannan I'm not asking about specific database.

Comment: @ypercube yes, it matters when you have more than 1 million records. What if it returns the first record by comparing with some later duplicate records, instead of comparing the whole records till the last one.

Comment: @AthaherSirnaik a_horse_with_no_name has already answered that. It will return the **value** `'Sam'` and no "record". Whether it retrieves that value from "row 1" or "row 100000" or from an index depends on many things. I think you are asking the wrong question. Are you interested in how the various DBMS will find all these values and how efficiently they do it? Or how to optimize such a query?

Comment: How could it matter? (This is a rhetorical question)

Answer (score 10):

[MySQL DISTINCT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/distinct-optimization.html)

> MySQL stops scanning any unused tables as soon as it finds the first match.

## Concept

`DISTINCT` returns the first match, yes! but what about returning the last match? The key idea is to sort the values first then conduct the distinction step. It can be done by using the syntax like so:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT column_name FROM
(SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name DESC)
```

#### First distinct value

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT Name,ID FROM Emp;
```

is the same with the syntax below but more explicit

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT generated.Name,generated.ID
FROM
    (
    SELECT Name,ID FROM Emp ORDER BY ID ASC
    ) AS generated
GROUP BY generated.Name
```

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Sam | 1 |
| Tom | 2 |

#### Last distinct value

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT generated.Name,generated.ID
FROM
    (
    SELECT Name,ID FROM Emp ORDER BY ID DESC
    ) AS generated
GROUP BY generated.Name
```

| Name | ID |
| --- | --- |
| Sam | 3 |
| Tom | 2 |

## Conclusion

Bare usage of `DISTINCT` will return the first occurrence. However, it can work either way by sorting the initial results first before conducting the distinction step.

Answer (score 9):

I think there's a misunderstanding here:
Your query does **not** return the records, only the distinct column values. Which, in your example, are '*Sam*' and '*Tom*'.

They have no particular order which can safely be expected. It may be the natural order, or the order in which they are processed on the database (completely depending on the database implementation), or semi-random (such as iterating over items in a set). The order may also vary depending on whether the result was retreived from the data or from the cache.

If you want a particular order, then specify it as order criterium:

```
select distinct Name from Emp order by Name asc
```

**If you want the distinct values and the first record containing it, use `group by`:**

```
select min(ID), Name from Emp group by Name
```